# C# check if a COM (Serial) port is already open

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Is there an easy way of programmatically checking if a serial COM port is already open/being used?

Normally I would use:

```
try
{
    // open port
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle the exception
}
```

However, I would like to programatically check so I can attempt to use another COM port or some such.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I needed something similar some time ago, to search for a device.

I obtained a list of available COM ports and then simply iterated over them, if it didn't throw an exception i tried to communicate with the device. A bit rough but working.

```
var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

foreach(var port in portNames) {
    //Try for every portName and break on the first working
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping for a more 'elegant' solution... but when all else fails 'use any means possible to make the program work'!

Comment: Just to be clear for some one who does not know SerialPort behavior the answer above does not use the port.Open which only checks if the CALLER has opened the port, not if say another application has it - for that an attempt to communicate through the port must be made and an exception thrown - port in use, access denied.

Comment: I don't like this "brute force" method. I think this will empty hardware receive buffers on all COM ports.

Answer (score 15):

This is how I did it:

```
      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr securityAttrs, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
```

then later on

```
        int dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0x40000000;

        var portName = "COM5";

        var isValid = SerialPort.GetPortNames().Any(x => string.Compare(x, portName, true) == 0);
        if (!isValid)
            throw new System.IO.IOException(string.Format("{0} port was not found", portName));

        //Borrowed from Microsoft's Serial Port Open Method :)
        SafeFileHandle hFile = CreateFile(@"\\.\" + portName, -1073741824, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 3, dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hFile.IsInvalid)
            throw new System.IO.IOException(string.Format("{0} port is already open", portName));

        hFile.Close();


        using (var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One))
        {
            serialPort.Open();
        }
```

Comment: What is the benefit to using this over catching the exception thrown when trying to use SerialPort.Open?

Comment: Because you dont want exceptions to control the flow of the application. Its cleaner to try to handle the problem ahead instead of tossing the exception than handling it.

Comment: @Jeff: However, you are running the risk that if someone opens the serial port the instant between when you check, and when you open it, your program will explode. By using exceptions, you can avert that potential disaster.

Comment: I strongly agree with @jcmcbeth: this approach is a race condition.

Comment: is there an alternative if the hFile.IsInvalid property is true instead of throwing an exception? what I should do if I want to continue and open the serial port?

Comment: @JoelMcBeth I see a library that does not throw exception when the port is open! so I have to check for it. but as mentioned in remark section of [SerialPort.Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.close?view=netframework-4.7.2) the close function does not release the resource instantly

Comment: Great answer. Allows you to iterate through all ports without throwing an exception for the inaccessible ones

Answer (score 1):

For people that cannot use `SerialPort.GetPortNames();` because they are not targeting `.net framework` (like in my case I am using .Net Core and NOT .Net Framework) here is what I ended up doing:

In command prompt if you type mode you get something like this:

[image]

mode is an executable located at `C:\Windows\System32\mode.com`. Just parse the results of that executable with a regex like this:

```
// Code that answers the question

var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\mode.com",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};

proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit(4000); // wait up to 4 seconds. It usually takes less than a second

// get ports being used
var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Now if you want to parse the output this is how I do it:

```
List<string> comPortsBeingUsed = new List<string>();
Regex.Replace(output, @"(?xi) status [\s\w]+? (COM\d) \b ", regexCapture =>
{
    comPortsBeingUsed.Add(regexCapture.Groups[1].Value);
    return null;
});

foreach(var item in comPortsBeingUsed)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"COM port {item} is in use");
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. I didn't know `mode.com` until today. But **be aware** for **multi language** usage, because `mode.com` is localised. So the RegEx can fail for Windows installations, when the translation of "status" is different. (In German it's the same word.)

Comment: In my command line tests I had a **reversed result**. Unused COM ports are listed by `mode.com` and used COM ports are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to open the next available port and did it like this.
Please note, is it not for WPF but for Windows Forms.
I populated a combobox with the com ports available.
Then I try to open the first one. If it fails, I select the next available item from the combobox. If the selected index did not change in the end, there were no alternate com ports available and we show a message.

```
private void GetPortNames()
{
    comboBoxComPort.Items.Clear();
    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        comboBoxComPort.Items.Add(s);
    }
    comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void OpenSerialPort()
{
    try
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = comboBoxComPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
        serialPort1.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        int SelectedIndex = comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex;
        if (comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex >= comboBoxComPort.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex++;
        }
        if (comboBoxComPort.SelectedIndex == SelectedIndex)
        {
            buttonOpenClose.Text = "Open Port";
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing port." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message, "Port Error!!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            OpenSerialPort();
        }
    }

    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        StartAsyncSerialReading();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) has an [*Open*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx) method, which will throw a few exceptions.
The reference above contains detailed examples.

See also, the [IsOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen.aspx) property.

A simple test:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SerPort1
{
class Program
{
    static private SerialPort MyPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
        OpenMyPort();
        Console.WriteLine("BaudRate {0}", MyPort.BaudRate);
        OpenMyPort();
        MyPort.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OpenMyPort()
    {
        try
        {
            MyPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error opening my port: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: IsOpen will only be truw if the Open() method was ever called. It won't say if the port has been opened by another app.

Comment: How do you skip the com1 if it doesn't exist?

Comment: The example uses COM1 as an illustration only. A non-existing device will cause the SerialPort constructor to raise an IOException : "The specified port could not be found or opened".

Comment: If you do that - all existing data in hardware buffers on all ports will be moved to software buffer (4096 bytes by default), and then destroyed when you close the port.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me (a simple helper method):

```
private string portName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns SerialPort Port State (Open / Closed)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal bool HasOpenPort()
    {
        bool portState = false;

        if (portName != string.Empty)
        {
            using (SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(portName))
            {
                foreach (var itm in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
                {
                    if (itm.Contains(serialPort.PortName))
                    {
                        if (serialPort.IsOpen) { portState = true; }
                        else { portState = false; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        else { System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: No Port Specified."); }

        return portState;
}
```

**Notes:**

- For more advanced technique(s) I recommend using [ManagementObjectSearcher Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=netframework-4.8).

 More info [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=netframework-4.8).

- For Arduino devices I would leave the Port Open.

- Recommend using a Try Catch block if you need to catch exceptions.

- Check also: "TimeoutException"

- More information on how to get SerialPort (Open) Exceptions [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.open?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void MobileMessages(string ComNo, string MobileMessage, string MobileNo)
    {
        if (SerialPort.IsOpen )
            SerialPort.Close();
        try
        {
            SerialPort.PortName = ComNo;
            SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;
            SerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            SerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            SerialPort.NewLine = Constants.vbCrLf;
            string message;
            message = MobileMessage;

            SerialPort.Open();
            if (SerialPort.IsOpen  )
            {
                SerialPort.Write("AT" + Constants.vbCrLf);
                SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + Constants.vbCrLf);
                SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=" + Strings.Chr(34) + MobileNo + Strings.Chr(34) + Constants.vbCrLf);
                SerialPort.Write(message + Strings.Chr(26));
            }
            else
                ("Port not available");
            SerialPort.Close();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

                message.show("The port " + ComNo + " does not exist, change port no ");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting with this problem for a few weeks now.   Thanks to the suggestions on here and from the site, https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/91090-c%23-serial-port-unauthorizedaccessexception/ .

I finally came up with a solution that seems to work.

The application I am working on allows a user to connect to a USB device and display data from it.

**The Problem I was battling.**   Along side the application I am writing, I use another serial terminal application for doing my testing.   Sometimes I forget to disconnect the COMport being used on the other application.  If I do, and try to connect with the application I am writing, I would get an “UnAuthorizedAccessException” error.    Along with this exception came some side effects, such as double lines of data being spit out and the application locking up on closing down.

**My Solution**

Thanks to the advice on here and the other site referenced, this was my solution.

```
        private void checkAndFillPortNameList()
        {
           SerialPort _testingSerialPort;


            AvailablePortNamesFound.Clear();
            List<string> availablePortNames = new List<string>();//mySerial.GetAvailablePortNames();

            foreach (string portName in SerialPortDataAccess.GetAvailablePortNames())
            {
                try
                {
                    _testingSerialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
                    _testingSerialPort.Open();

                    if (_testingSerialPort.IsOpen)
                    {
                        availablePortNames.Add(portName);
                        _testingSerialPort.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
 
                }
            }
            availablePortNames.Sort();
            AvailablePortNamesFound = new ObservableCollection<string>(availablePortNames);
        }
```

This routine connects to a combobox which holds the available Comports for selection.   If a Comport is already, in use by another application, that port name will not appear in the combo box.

Answer (score -2):

You can try folloing code to check whether a port already open or not. I'm assumming you dont know specificaly which port you want to check.

```
foreach (var portName in Serial.GetPortNames()
{
  SerialPort port = new SerialPort(portName);
  if (port.IsOpen){
    /** do something **/
  }
  else {
    /** do something **/
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if people said why they downvoted, so other people can know why this is wrong.  I am assuming this is the reason:

IsOpen will only be truw if the Open() method was ever called. It won't say if the port has been opened by another app. – Mark Cidade Oct 12 '08 at 14:28

Comment: If the comport does not exist at all, say port 20, you can still check if it's open returning false and this may mislead the developer to try and open the port... best to check if the port exists before even assuming if it's open or close.

Comment: The reason why it was downvoted is because this solution will only work for ports opened within the own application not system wide. And thus it's not really helpful. Unfortunately. I'm also looking for a nice way to check but there doesn't seem to be more than an try..catch block.

Comment: as @AllDayPiano said check the remark section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen?view=netframework-4.7.2