# Function to find available serial port and open it for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serial-port

Instead hard coding the port name, how can i make my program find the correct COM port? I don't want to be given the option of which COM port to chose. I want my program to directly Open it.

```
public string portName = "COM5";
```

Comment: take a look at this question 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1081871/10859114

Comment: This post may be helpful
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850367/c-sharp-how-to-detect-serial-port-programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850367/c-sharp-how-to-detect-serial-port-programatically)

Comment: These solutions were not of help in my case. I am trying to use the file for a Unity based project