# Establish a communication between a development board and C# that autodetect the COM port

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino-ide

I'm developing an app in Visual Studio using C#. This app should be able to connect to a development board, by finding the COM port by itself. I'm using one of the answer of this post: [How to auto-detect Arduino COM port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293889/how-to-auto-detect-arduino-com-port) the one that use SerialPort.GetPortNames(). I tried to do stablish a connection, but it didn't work. The thing is I don't know if the problem is the code I use in the development board or it is other thing.
The code uploaded to the board:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {

    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only

  }
  establishContact();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if  (Serial.available() > 0){ //Check if the serial port is available 
 
      String inputRead = Serial.readString(); //Read what is entering on the port 
  }
}

void establishContact() {

  while (Serial.available() <= 0) {

    Serial.print('A');   // send a capital A

    delay(300);

  }
}
```

I'm kind of new to C# and arduino coding.

I have search but I didn't found anything. What I want is to establish a connection and then send data.

Comment: There's some code in the following posts that may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971845/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425