# UnauthorizedAccessException - port not already open

Tags: c#, .net, windows, serial-port

I'm using the SerialPort C# class on a few different computers for a particular peripheral device, and on one of the computers, SerialPort.Open ALWAYS returns an UnauthorizedAccessException.

I've used both Microsoft's Process Explorer utility and this enum serial ports tool: http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html to "verify" that the COM port is not being used and I've run the program after a fresh restart with the same results.

I noticed that the .NET documentation specifies:

> UnauthorizedAccessException    Access is denied to the port.
>   - or - The current process, or another process on the system, already has the specified COM port open either by a SerialPort instance or in
>   unmanaged code.

I cannot find any other documentation or detailed replies explaining what other things could cause an access denial other than the port being already open/in use.

Anyone else have any ideas or tips?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195483/c-sharp-check-if-a-com-serial-port-is-already-open

Comment: Sometimes when I'm debugging from Visual Studio and the app crashes, the port never gets properly closed. My guess is that the port reference is still active in VS but I have no proof. Anyways, restarting VS fixes it every time. Keep in mind that virtual serial port file handles are found slightly differently in Process Explorer