# How to get the port from GSM Modem using AT Command

Tags: c#, gsm, at-command

I'm trying to make an SMS Application using AT Command. What I want to know is that how can I get the port of GSM Modem instead of hard coding it?

Below is my sample of my code.

```
private void SendSMSTo(string cnum)
    {
        SerialPort _serialPort;

        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM9", 115200);
        //instead of hard coding the port COM9 I want to get the port from GSM Modem

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Open();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1\r");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + cnum + "\"\r\n");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Write(computation() + "\x1A");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        _serialPort.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# check if a COM (Serial) port is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195483/c-sharp-check-if-a-com-serial-port-is-already-open)

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to get the port from GSM Modem`?, the `COM` port you use for comm is a PC side issue, and modem is not aware of

Comment: What I mean is, is there another possible way to find the GSM Modem COM port through code? Because I don't to hard code it.

Comment: You should [**never use Thread.Sleep like that**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064206/23118). And you need to [wait properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15591673/23118) before sending the sms payload,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Windows guy, but I don't think your question is really tight to Windows.

As said by @Hessam, you cannot ask the modem to tell you the port it is connected to as you can't discuss with the modem because you don't know the port...

What I would try is to test all possible ports to detect the right one and only then send your SMS. For that, you may loop from `COM1` up to `COMXXX` (I don't know the limit but put it big enough...) and try to send an `AT` command for which you know the reply. If you get the expected reply, you got the right port; if not, try the next one. If I remember well the `AT` command `AT` just replies `OK`. That would be the simplest option. Otherwise, you may choose `ATI` which provide full information about the modem, or one of `AT+GMI`, `AT+GMM` or `AT+GMR`, etc which provide partial information.

So you would have two functions:

- `detectModemPort()` that would reply with the port number (or port name) if found or with an error
- `SendSMSTo(string port, string cnum)` which will first open a serial connection on port `port` (which exists because we just detected it) and then send the SMS to `cnum`.

You may also want to have a look at [this question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/414280/how-do-i-view-a-list-of-devices-from-the-command-line-in-windows) on SuperUser. It looks like there is a `devcon.exe` command to discover devices connected to a computer, but I don't have a Windows bon to try it.